# QT based Win7 app can't cope with the death of an I/O device

Tags: c++, windows, qt, serial-port, hung

I'm writing a QT based native c++ app that uses QtSerialPort library under Win7. It communicates with it periodically(*say every 5seconds*).
Problem is: the device that my app connects to via serial port, has power loss issues(can't change this). When this happens my app becomes hung and immortal: can't be killed by windows task manager or by **process hacker**(*a nice replacement for windows task manager*)' termination facilities. Soft restart is the best solution at the hand.

Now how can my app cope with such device situation?

Answer (score 0):

I would submit this question to Qt's interest mailing list (interest@qt-project.org).  Since the QtSerialPort library is fairly new, bugs can appear when a wide user base starts using it.  There is a good chance that the developers who wrote the library can give you a better solution or they find that this is a bug in their code and fix it.